# Creating a customized language using Python

Tags: python, sage

I have started playing with Sage recently, and I've come to suspect that the standard Python `int` is wrapped in a customized class called `Integer` in Sage. If I type in `type(1)` in Python, I get `<type 'int'>`, however, if I type in the same thing in the sage prompt I get `<type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>`.

If I wanted to replace Python `int` (or `list` or `dict`) with my own custom class, how might it be done? How difficult would it be (e.g. could I do it entirely in Python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addendum to the other answers: when running any code, Sage has a preprocessing step which converts the Sage-Python to true Python (which is then executed). This is done by the `preparse` function, e.g.

```
sage: preparse('a = 1')
'a = Integer(1)'
sage: preparse('2^40')
'Integer(2)**Integer(40)'
sage: preparse('F.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)')
"F = PolynomialRing(ZZ, names=('x',)); (x,) = F._first_ngens(1)"
```

This step is precisely what allows the transparent use of `Integer`s (in place of `int`s) and the other non-standard syntax (like the polynomial ring example above and `[a..b]` etc).

As far as I understand, this is the only way to completely transparently use replacements for the built-in types in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to subclass all of Python's built-in types.  For example:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

i = MyInt(2)
#i is now an instance of MyInt, but still will behave entirely like an integer.
```

However, you need to explicitly say each integer is a member of MyInt.  So `type(1)` will still be `int`, you'll need to do `type(MyInt(1))`.

Hopefully that's close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Sage, it's easy. Sage has complete control of its own REPL (read-evaluate-print loop), so it can parse the commands you give it and make the parts of your expression into whatever classes it wants. It is not so easy to have standard Python automatically use your integer type for integer literals, however.  Simply reassigning the built-in `int()` to some other type won't do it. You could probably do it with an import filter, that scans each file imported for (say) integer literals and replaces them with `MyInt(42)` or whatever.